# 404 error when passing parameter to method on WebAPi controller in Area

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

This seems to be a rather common problem per all the questions on StackOverflow regarding this but I've not found a solution yet that has worked in my case. For simplicity I am trying to POST a single string parameter to a method on a WebAPI controller in my MVC project. When doing so, I am getting a 404 error.  If I remove the parameter and just call the method, it returns just fine, so I seem to have a routing problem with parameters.  The controller is in an `Area`.

Here is what I have:

**ProductController.cs**

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string UpdateCD(string name)
    {
        return name;
    }

}
```

**ProductsAreaRegistration.cs**

```
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Products";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {

        context.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "ProductsAPI_Debug_Localhost",
           routeTemplate: "Products/api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional } //controller = "Home", action = "Index",
       );

        context.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ProductsAPI_Server",
            routeTemplate: "bcnet.Net/Products/api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional } //controller = "Home", action = "Index",
        );


    }
```

**Global.asax.cs**

```
        /// <param name="e">Event arguments.</param>
        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new StructureMapControllerFactory());
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new StructureMapDependencyResolver();
        }
```

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)// RouteCollection routes
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
}
```

**Finally, just a simple Ajax request:**

```
    var name = "Mary";

    var request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $("#URL").val(),
            data: "{ name : \"" + name + "\" }",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "text"
            });

        request.done(function (msg)
        {

        });

        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus)
        {

        });
```

Again, if I make the method on the controller without a parameter, it returns just fine, but as soon as I have the parameter, the 404 error happens.

Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: Can you try with `public string UpdateCD([FromBody]string name)`?

Comment: I just tried it and it actually hit my method but it did not pass in the parameter, the value was null.

Comment: What if you change the type to `object`?

Comment: I tried that too, it passes in null, but when I look in my developer tools in the browser I can see that it's sending the data.  This is what my browser is sending:  `{ name : "Mary" }`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the answer to this situation.  Turns out when passing primitive types to the WebAPI there are some things to keep in mind:

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/

Turns out the 404 issue is a misleading error, it's really not a bad route. The easiest solution is to not pass primitive types but rather to pass in a class.

My updated code:

**ProductController:**

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}


[HttpPost]
public string UpdateCD([FromBody]Person person)
{
    return person.FirstName;
}
```

**My AJAX request:**

```
    var name = "Mary";

    var request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $("#URL").val(),
            data: "{ FirstName : \"" + name + "\" }",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "text"
            });

        request.done(function (msg)
        {

        });

        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus)
        {

        });
}
```

Comment: I found this same issue. I'd love to know what the real issue is here. I solved my problem by making class to house my parameter. Which is absurd as all I wanted to pass was a bool parameter. It works however.